# Tensorflow queues hang

Tags: python, tensorflow

This Cifar10 model, altered somewhat from the Cifar10 tutorial, seems to spike and then hang, never returning control of the program to the interpreter.  It has been suggesting that it is on account of having not called `.start_queue_runners`.  However, there doesn't seem to be any code in the original Cifar10 tutorial that calls `.start_queue_runners`, and it runs just fine. (I'm using the single-GPU training code `cifar10_train.py`... the multiple-GPU code DOES call that method)

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import functools
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import zipfile
import tarfile
import sys


# Process images of this size. Note that this differs from the original CIFAR
# image size of 32 x 32. If one alters this number, then the entire model
# architecture will change and any model would need to be retrained.
IMAGE_SIZE = 24

# Global constants describing the CIFAR-10 data set.
NUM_CLASSES = 10
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN = 50000
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL = 10000


def maybe_download_and_extract():
    main_directory = "../data/"
    cifar_10_directory = main_directory+"cifar_10/"
    if not os.path.exists(main_directory):
        os.makedirs(main_directory)
    if not os.path.exists(cifar_10_directory):
        url = "http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-binary.tar.gz"
        filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        file_path = os.path.join(main_directory, filename)
        zip_cifar_10 = file_path
        file_path, _ = urlretrieve(url=url, filename=file_path, reporthook=print_download_progress)

        print()
        print("Download finished. Extracting files.")
        if file_path.endswith(".zip"):
            zipfile.ZipFile(file=file_path, mode="r").extractall(main_directory)
        elif file_path.endswith((".tar.gz", ".tgz")):
            tarfile.open(name=file_path, mode="r:gz").extractall(main_directory)
        print("Done.")

        os.rename(main_directory+"cifar-10-batches-bin", cifar_10_directory)
        os.remove(zip_cifar_10)
    return (
        [os.path.join(cifar_10_directory, 'data_batch_{}.bin'.format(i)) for i in range(1,6)],
        [os.path.join(cifar_10_directory, 'test_batch.bin')]
    )

class Cifar10Record(list):
    # This class represents a Cifar10 thing that we read from the Cifar10 files.
    # Note that it is a tensorflow-type-thing, so data *moves through* here, as we read it (like a placeholder, or whatever)
    # So one record object is sufficient to feed a whole training pipeline
    label_bytes = 1    # 2 for CIFAR-100
    height = 32
    width = 32
    depth = 3
    # Every record consists of a label followed by the image, with a
    # fixed number of bytes for each.
    image_bytes = height * width * depth
    record_bytes = label_bytes + image_bytes
    def __init__(self, filenames):
        # This is going to create the tf graph that reads a record.
        self.filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
        #1st part of graph: a record reader, that will get filenames from the filename_queue
        self.reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=Cifar10Record.record_bytes)
        #2nd part, the reader is reading files from the filename_queue
        self.key, value = self.reader.read(self.filename_queue)
        # Convert from a string to a vector of uint8 that is record_bytes long.
        record = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
        # The first bytes represent the label, which we convert from uint8->int32.
        label = tf.cast(
                tf.strided_slice(record, [0], [Cifar10Record.label_bytes]), tf.int32)
        label.set_shape([1])
        self.label = tf.one_hot(label, 10, on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0)

        # The remaining bytes after the label represent the image, which we reshape
        # from [depth * height * width] to [depth, height, width].
        depth_major = tf.reshape(
                tf.strided_slice(record, [Cifar10Record.label_bytes],
                    [Cifar10Record.record_bytes]),
                [Cifar10Record.depth, Cifar10Record.height, Cifar10Record.width])
        # Convert from [depth, height, width] to [height, width, depth].
        self.uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])
        self.float32image = tf.cast(self.uint8image, tf.float32)
        #self.distorted_image = self.distorted_input_branch()
        self.image = self.undistorted_input_branch()

    def undistorted_input_branch(self):
        """Construct input for CIFAR evaluation using the Reader ops.
        """
        height = IMAGE_SIZE
        width = IMAGE_SIZE

        # Image processing for evaluation.
        # Crop the central [height, width] of the image.
        resized_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(self.float32image, height, width)

        # Subtract off the mean and divide by the variance of the pixels.
        float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(resized_image)

        # Set the shapes of tensors.
        float_image.set_shape([height, width, 3])
        return float_image

    def batched_input(self, num_examples_per_epoch, batch_size, shuffle=True, distorted=False):
        """Construct a queued batch of images and labels.
        Returns:
            images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, height, width, 3] size.
            labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
        """

        # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
        min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
        min_queue_examples = int(num_examples_per_epoch *
                                   min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)

        image = self.distorted_image if distorted else self.image
        label = self.label
        print ('Filling queue with %d CIFAR images before starting to train. '
            'This will take a few minutes.' % min_queue_examples)


        # Create a queue that shuffles the examples, and then
        # read 'batch_size' images + labels from the example queue.
        NUM_PREPROCESS_THREADS = 16
        print(batch_size)
        images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                [image, label],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                num_threads=NUM_PREPROCESS_THREADS,
                capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
                min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)

        return images, tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size,10])

train_files, test_files = maybe_download_and_extract()
train_data = Cifar10Record(train_files).batched_input(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN, 100)
test_data = Cifar10Record(test_files).batched_input(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL, 100)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_data)
    input("foo!")
```

Comment: Hello again, have you tried using `start_queue_runners`? The original example is using `MonitoredTrainingSession` which is doing a number of things for you, including that: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L557

Comment: "The original example is using MonitoredTrainingSession which is doing a number of things for you, including that" AHA!!!  I did try using `start_queue_runners` and it is working.  However, at this point, I am feeling confident enough to translate the whole thing into the "new way" to do datasets.  I'll post both solutions here.  Thanks for all of your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment from @de1, the reasoning is that a `MonitoredTrainingSession` calls `start_queue_runners` or does something like it.  Here is functioning code that starts the queue runners properly:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import functools
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import zipfile
import tarfile
import sys


# Process images of this size. Note that this differs from the original CIFAR
# image size of 32 x 32. If one alters this number, then the entire model
# architecture will change and any model would need to be retrained.
IMAGE_SIZE = 24

# Global constants describing the CIFAR-10 data set.
NUM_CLASSES = 10
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN = 50000
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL = 10000


def maybe_download_and_extract():
    main_directory = "../data/"
    cifar_10_directory = main_directory+"cifar_10/"
    if not os.path.exists(main_directory):
        os.makedirs(main_directory)
    if not os.path.exists(cifar_10_directory):
        url = "http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-binary.tar.gz"
        filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        file_path = os.path.join(main_directory, filename)
        zip_cifar_10 = file_path
        file_path, _ = urlretrieve(url=url, filename=file_path, reporthook=print_download_progress)

        print()
        print("Download finished. Extracting files.")
        if file_path.endswith(".zip"):
            zipfile.ZipFile(file=file_path, mode="r").extractall(main_directory)
        elif file_path.endswith((".tar.gz", ".tgz")):
            tarfile.open(name=file_path, mode="r:gz").extractall(main_directory)
        print("Done.")

        os.rename(main_directory+"cifar-10-batches-bin", cifar_10_directory)
        os.remove(zip_cifar_10)
    return (
        [os.path.join(cifar_10_directory, 'data_batch_{}.bin'.format(i)) for i in range(1,6)],
        [os.path.join(cifar_10_directory, 'test_batch.bin')]
    )

class Cifar10Record(list):
    # This class represents a Cifar10 thing that we read from the Cifar10 files.
    # Note that it is a tensorflow-type-thing, so data *moves through* here, as we read it (like a placeholder, or whatever)
    # So one record object is sufficient to feed a whole training pipeline
    label_bytes = 1    # 2 for CIFAR-100
    height = 32
    width = 32
    depth = 3
    # Every record consists of a label followed by the image, with a
    # fixed number of bytes for each.
    image_bytes = height * width * depth
    record_bytes = label_bytes + image_bytes
    def __init__(self, filenames):
        # This is going to create the tf graph that reads a record.
        self.filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
        #1st part of graph: a record reader, that will get filenames from the filename_queue
        self.reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=Cifar10Record.record_bytes)
        #2nd part, the reader is reading files from the filename_queue
        self.key, value = self.reader.read(self.filename_queue)
        # Convert from a string to a vector of uint8 that is record_bytes long.
        record = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
        # The first bytes represent the label, which we convert from uint8->int32.
        label = tf.cast(
                tf.strided_slice(record, [0], [Cifar10Record.label_bytes]), tf.int32)
        label.set_shape([1])
        self.label = tf.one_hot(label, 10, on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0)

        # The remaining bytes after the label represent the image, which we reshape
        # from [depth * height * width] to [depth, height, width].
        depth_major = tf.reshape(
                tf.strided_slice(record, [Cifar10Record.label_bytes],
                    [Cifar10Record.record_bytes]),
                [Cifar10Record.depth, Cifar10Record.height, Cifar10Record.width])
        # Convert from [depth, height, width] to [height, width, depth].
        self.uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])
        self.float32image = tf.cast(self.uint8image, tf.float32)
        #self.distorted_image = self.distorted_input_branch()
        self.image = self.undistorted_input_branch()

    def undistorted_input_branch(self):
        """Construct input for CIFAR evaluation using the Reader ops.
        """
        height = IMAGE_SIZE
        width = IMAGE_SIZE

        # Image processing for evaluation.
        # Crop the central [height, width] of the image.
        resized_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(self.float32image, height, width)

        # Subtract off the mean and divide by the variance of the pixels.
        float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(resized_image)

        # Set the shapes of tensors.
        float_image.set_shape([height, width, 3])
        return float_image

    def batched_input(self, num_examples_per_epoch, batch_size, shuffle=True, distorted=False):
        """Construct a queued batch of images and labels.
        Returns:
            images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, height, width, 3] size.
            labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
        """

        # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
        min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
        min_queue_examples = int(num_examples_per_epoch *
                                   min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)

        image = self.distorted_image if distorted else self.image
        label = self.label
        print ('Filling queue with %d CIFAR images before starting to train. '
            'This will take a few minutes.' % min_queue_examples)


        # Create a queue that shuffles the examples, and then
        # read 'batch_size' images + labels from the example queue.
        NUM_PREPROCESS_THREADS = 16
        print(batch_size)
        images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                [image, label],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                num_threads=NUM_PREPROCESS_THREADS,
                capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
                min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)

        return images, tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size,10])

train_files, test_files = maybe_download_and_extract()
train_queue = Cifar10Record(train_files)
train_data = train_queue.batched_input(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN, 100)
test_queue = Cifar10Record(test_files)
test_data = test_queue.batched_input(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL, 100)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    sess.run(train_data)
    input("foo!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested in reading Cifar10 records in the "new way" with the Dataset API might benefit from this answer:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import functools
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import zipfile
import tarfile
import sys

# Process images of this size. Note that this differs from the original CIFAR
# image size of 32 x 32. If one alters this number, then the entire model
# architecture will change and any model would need to be retrained.
IMAGE_SIZE = 24
BYTE = 1
KB = 1024*BYTE
MB = 1024*KB

# Global constants describing the CIFAR-10 data set.
NUM_CLASSES = 10
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN = 50000
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL = 10000

def print_download_progress(count, block_size, total_size):
    pct_complete = float(count * block_size) / total_size
    msg = "\r- Download progress: {0:.1%}".format(pct_complete)
    sys.stdout.write(msg)
    sys.stdout.flush()


def maybe_download_and_extract():
    main_directory = "../data/"
    cifar_10_directory = main_directory+"cifar_10/"
    if not os.path.exists(main_directory):
        os.makedirs(main_directory)
    if not os.path.exists(cifar_10_directory):
        url = "http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-binary.tar.gz"
        filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        file_path = os.path.join(main_directory, filename)
        zip_cifar_10 = file_path
        file_path, _ = urlretrieve(url=url, filename=file_path, reporthook=print_download_progress)

        print()
        print("Download finished. Extracting files.")
        if file_path.endswith(".zip"):
            zipfile.ZipFile(file=file_path, mode="r").extractall(main_directory)
        elif file_path.endswith((".tar.gz", ".tgz")):
            tarfile.open(name=file_path, mode="r:gz").extractall(main_directory)
        print("Done.")

        os.rename(main_directory+"cifar-10-batches-bin", cifar_10_directory)
        os.remove(zip_cifar_10)
    return (
        [os.path.join(cifar_10_directory, 'data_batch_{}.bin'.format(i)) for i in range(1,6)],
        [os.path.join(cifar_10_directory, 'test_batch.bin')]
    )

class Cifar10Record(object):
    # This class represents a Cifar10 thing that we read from the Cifar10 files.
    # Note that it is a tensorflow-type-thing, so data *moves through* here, as we read it (like a placeholder, or whatever)
    # So one record object is sufficient to feed a whole training pipeline
    label_bytes = 1    # 2 for CIFAR-100
    height = 32
    width = 32
    depth = 3
    # Every record consists of a label followed by the image, with a
    # fixed number of bytes for each.
    image_bytes = height * width * depth
    record_bytes = label_bytes + image_bytes
    def __init__(self, filenames):
        # This is going to create the tf graph that reads a record.
        self.filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
        self.dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(filenames, Cifar10Record.record_bytes, buffer_size=1*MB)
        self.dataset = self.dataset.map(Cifar10Record._parse_function)
        self.dataset = self.dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1*MB)
        self.dataset = self.dataset.batch(100)
        self.iterator = self.dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
        self.next_input = self.iterator.get_next()

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_function(value):
        record = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
        # The first bytes represent the label, which we convert from uint8->int32.
        label = tf.cast(
                tf.strided_slice(record, [0], [Cifar10Record.label_bytes]), tf.int32)
        label.set_shape([1])
        label = tf.one_hot(label, 10, on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0)

        # The remaining bytes after the label represent the image, which we reshape
        # from [depth * height * width] to [depth, height, width].
        depth_major = tf.reshape(
                tf.strided_slice(record, [Cifar10Record.label_bytes],
                    [Cifar10Record.record_bytes]),
                [Cifar10Record.depth, Cifar10Record.height, Cifar10Record.width])
        # Convert from [depth, height, width] to [height, width, depth].
        uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])
        float32image = tf.cast(uint8image, tf.float32)
        return float32image, label


train_files, test_files = maybe_download_and_extract()
train_data = Cifar10Record(train_files)
test_data = Cifar10Record(test_files)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_data.iterator.initializer)
    print(sess.run(train_data.next_input))
```

Comment: That's great. Perhaps submit a PR to update their example.

Comment: This is a *greatly* simplified version of their example.  I do not even have access to the hardware to test it on multiple gpus, which their example is capable of running on.  Maybe if I find that I have a week to spare and find a few dozen grand on the sidewalk to buy a server with a handful of Teslas in it I'll submit a PR.  :p